# iPhone UILocalNotification load specific view

Tags: ios, xcode, uilocalnotification

I have my local notification working, but when I click View to come back to the app, in the app delegate I am trying to load a specific view, but it wont take.  Is this possible or not?  It always just comes back to the last view viewed.

Comment: Some code would clarify the question, can you provide some?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you tap "View" on the notification, it takes you back to your application, and your application shows whatever it was showing before (if it was backgrounded) or is launched.

If you need to show a particular UI in response to the notification, consider implementing the `<UIApplicationDelegate>` method [`-[<UIApplicationDelegate> application:didReceiveLocalNotification:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW22).  In that method you can inspect the notification and transition to the appropriate interface.