# iOS: How to show an alert and play sound endlessly through push notification

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am designing an app which is like a Find my Phone app, which plays an alert sound endlessly and an alert is shown even if the app is not launched. The alert will open the app if dismissed. I checked the notification sound but it only plays for 30 seconds when the phone is locked. Can someone help me with this?
Thank you for helping

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I play an alarm sound for more than 30 seconds like the alarm clock pro app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543726/how-do-i-play-an-alarm-sound-for-more-than-30-seconds-like-the-alarm-clock-pro-a)

Answer (score 1):

**According to Apple docs you can not play sound more than 30 seconds.**

> Place custom sound files in your app bundle or in the Library/Sounds
>   folder of your app’s container directory. Custom sounds must be under
>   30 seconds when played. If a custom sound is over that limit, the
>   default system sound is played instead.

Here is reference apple doc link - https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SupportingNotificationsinYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH4-SW1