# Alarm clock functionality for closed apps in Xamarin

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I want to create an "alarm clock" -app which executes an alarm tone at a configurable time, also when the app is closed.

For android I found AlarmManager but it doesn't work if the app is closed. 
Is this possible to achieve this functionality for iOS and Android?

Comment: What's the difference between your app and system alarm clock? Can you use a local notification to achieve that?

Comment: It is a app in the medical area; the patient has to do certain exercises at specific times. So you could do this with the system-alarm-clock and just open the app manually.

Answer (score 2):

You can fire a local notification at specific times to alert people do certain exercises. Every time you need to add an exercise, just add a local notification with specific time, and you can set the `sound`, `content`, `isRepeat` and etc.

For how to set a notification:

If you are using Xamarin.forms: you have to use [dependency-service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/) to implement the local-notifications in `iOS` and `android` project.

For example, in your `xamarin.forms` project:

```
public interface ISetLocalNotification
{
    void noti(string time, string content...);
}
```

And implement in both iOS and Android project.

**iOS**: [local-notifications-in-ios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/deprecated/local-notifications-in-ios)

**Android**: [local-notifications-in-android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/notifications/local-notifications)

And when you want to use :

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DependencyService.Get<ISetLocalNotification>().noti("12:00","123"...);

    }
}
```

Comment: As I understand this only will send a notification with a sound. Is there a possibility to start an annoying sound which the user has to deactivate like an alarm clock?

Comment: @Harald Check the two answers in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543726/how-do-i-play-an-alarm-sound-for-more-than-30-seconds-like-the-alarm-clock-pro-a). And here is the [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SupportingNotificationsinYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH4-SW1) that Apple says you can not play sound more than 30 seconds.

Answer (score -1):

NOT THE SOLUTION:

---

There's several ways of doing this. It wasn't clear if you are using Xamarin Forms or not. But assuming you are using Xamarin forms, here's a great [example with an official Xamarin video](https://robgibbens.com/backgrounding-with-xamarin-forms/). But essentially, you are going to be running some code in the background while your app is not open. Just enable the permissions to do so, and check for time, so that the app plays the alarm when it is time.

If you are not using forms, you don't need to create the interface, and so it's much easier.

Comment: Sorry for -1, but the link that you have provided for iOS is not for running the background code at desired time. The code will run in the background, but when the system decides to do so. Also while I don't see anything wrong on that link, there is nothing official there.

Comment: @IvanIčin good catch! I fixed it. I was looking at the other really good example and ended up sharing the wrong one ( https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-background-tasks/ )

Comment: I am not sure about this. This is about keeping the app running while in the background... It should be fairly limited according to the description.

Comment: How would this look like with a service? There is the portability to trigger a service every 15 min (smallest interval) but this is not precise enough for a alarm clock.